# Can HTTPS be intercepted or modified without modifying the client?

Tags: security, ssl, https, tls1.2

My understanding of HTTPS is that the encryption and decryption is done in the process, and any data that passes through the OS is encrypted.

Most HTTPS MITM tools work by editing the HTTPS client to send requests via a proxy, and/or accept invalid SSL certificates.

Given:

- Program A is a binary program that contains an HTTPS client (that does not use a proxy and only accepts valid SSL certs).
- Program A cannot be modified.
- The OS can be modified, instrumented etc.

Would this mean the responses processed by the program have definitely come from the server and are not modified?

Does HTTPS have protection for replay attacks (sending the same encrypted response that was recorded earlier)?

Comment: The OS controls all programs, so it is impossible to have a situation where the OS can be changed but the program cannot. SSL/TLS protects against replay except for 0-RTT data in TLS1.3 (only) which HTTPS apps generally don't use.

Comment: If the OS can be modified which means I can control the DNS responses and the local certificate store. That means I can do or fake almost anything including setting up MITM with a fake certificate.

Answer (score 3):

> Given:
>
> - Program A is a binary program that contains an HTTPS client (that does not use a proxy and only accepts valid SSL certs).
> - Program A cannot be modified.
> - The OS can be modified, instrumented etc.

The question is, what are valid SSL certificates, how does the browser know? Firefox has its own certificate store, but Google Chrome uses the OS certificate store (they are creating thier own certificate store). Firefox however, does not load the OS certificate store by default. So your reasoning holds up for some browsers.

Being able to edit the trusted certificates on browsers is used, quite extensively, on intranet sites by corporations, so they don't have to get their certificates signed by a trusted third party.

As for your last question, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/are-ssl-encrypted-requests-vulnerable-to-replay-attacks explains this very well.

Sources:
https://www.zdnet.com/article/chrome-will-soon-have-its-own-dedicated-certificate-root-store/
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox

Comment: So by adding a self-signed cert to the OS cert store and redirecting the DNS to their own server, a MITM could easily be accomplished without editing the program (only the OS)?

Comment: What if the program used its own hard coded cert store and used DNSSEC?

Comment: @zino if the program uses its own hard coded cert store, DNSSEC isn't needed for it to be secure.